# EXIF data in JPEG file

Tags: java, android, exif

Write custom data as a `Exif data in a JPEG image file` using `ExifInterface` in Android

Would like to `write/add` custom `tags/exif` data in `JPEG file` like name, age, etc... Right now i am able to write default values like `Geo location data, attributes etc...` but can i write custom data in JPEG image using `ExifInterface (Android)`

Is this possible or any other alternative to maintain these short of information with image

Comment: Hi. I have tried to write custom data using ExifInterface, but it's won't to write it, so I have looked at source codes of this class. It's uses a native class, I have looked that class to, and found, that it's impossible. If you have found the solution of this problem, please add the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Android's ExifInterface only lets you write exif tags that are "recognized." You can find SOME of the recognized exif tags in the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

But the good news is, there's more exif tags that's not mentioned in the Android API. 
Bad news is, I still haven't found a library that lists all usable exif tags

After researching and experimenting for hours, I found that the following tag works:

> "UserComment"

So the following code snippet will work:

```
String mString = "Your message here";     
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path_of_your_jpeg_file);
exif.setAttribute("UserComment", mString);
exif.saveAttributes();
```

I'm still trying to find out which other exif tags are allowed, but for now, this should do the trick.

Comment: after I added "UserComment", the Image Disappear from the gallery!! - does somebody face this problem?

Comment: @ baekacaek  after writing custom attribute how to re read it? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To do this use the Android [EXIF Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

1. Add your Attributes using this method
   public void setAttribute (String tag, String value)
2. Make a new version of the JPEG with this method. 
   public void saveAttributes ()