# Android Create Custom Exif attributes for an image file

Tags: android, jpeg, exif

currently i am trying to add custom exif tag/data to an image file that is in photo album.

I am able to modify the existing tags defined in [`ExifInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class

However, i want to store custom data, such as user id of my app user, but it seems there is no way i can create a custom exif attribute

the closest solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851425/android-exif-data-in-jpeg-file), but does not work,

Answer (score 8):

Try saving the Exif data with the tag:

> "UserComment"

Code:

```
String mString = "Your message here";     
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path_of_your_jpeg_file);
exif.setAttribute("UserComment", mString);
exif.saveAttributes();
```

You can put anything you want in there (as String) and simply parse the string. I wish we could create and name our own exif tags, but the reality is that we can't. So this is the best solution I came up with.

Comment: I have tried with ObjExifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", "Notes..."); but its not work.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot use an existing exif attribute (such as "UserComment" or "ImageDescription"), then you are out of luck with using `ExifInterface`.

Exif attributes are represented as binary tag numbers with the values encoded in binary data formats.  `ExifInterface` class abstracts this away from the programmer, and provides a `setAttribute` method where the tag and the value are supplied as strings.  Behind the scenes, it maps between the string form and the corresponding binary attribute representation.

The problem is that the `ExifInterface` class only knows how to map a fixed set of attributes.  Furthermore, the API doesn't provide a way to add the descriptors for new (e.g. custom) exif attributes to its mapping tables.

If you are really desperate, the alternatives are:

- Look for an alternative library that works with Android.
- Do nasty things with reflection to add extra mappings to `ExifInterface`'s internal (`private`) mapping tables.  If you try this, you will need to deal with the fact that the `ExifInterface`'s implementation has changed radically over time.  (In some older versions, the encoding and decoding of attributes is implemented in a native code library!)

Comment: The answer is actually correct and explains why it doesn't work when not using one of these tags : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface

Answer (score 3):

Save the Exif data with the tag `"ImageDescription"`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Code

```
try {
  String imageDescription = "Your image description";     
  ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file_name_of_jpeg);
  exif.setAttribute("ImageDescription", imageDescription);
  exif.saveAttributes();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // handle the error
}
```

Comment: Info: According to an Android Studio warning this requires API Level 24+.