# android save caption with image on SD card

Tags: android, image

Please can you help me and told me that how we can save the caption of image with the image on sdcard?

I already save the image and its works perfectly but I dont know how to save the caption with it?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to use EXIF (Google it) if you want to save metadata with an image file.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851425/android-exif-data-in-jpeg-file